# UIActionSheet button mask messed up after showing QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, uiactionsheet, qlpreviewcontroller

I am working on a photo-sharing app. The users can take and upload photos, and I use an UIActionSheet to provide selection whether to take a new photo with the camera or choose an existing photo from the library. In an other view I have a list of uploaded photos, and if the user taps on a photo it becomes full screen with QLPreviewController. My problem is that if the preview controller was once opened in full screen, in the completely different view controller of upload the button masks of the action sheet messes up this way:

[image: Messed up UIActionSheet masks]

Any idea how to avoid this (obviously) bug of the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be issue with `statusBarOrientation`.

Try to add

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
```

in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Splendid! This was driving me crazy... You need to put the code AFTER the modal View Controller finishes going away. I found it works really well to put this code before the UIActionSheet is presented